# how to edit a audio file mp3?

Tags: audio

Can I edit an audio/mp3 file and do changes in the lyrics ??

Answer (score 4):

For very simple editing, take a look at [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), however, to do what you want is very awkward - you will need to record the edited lyrics, then mix them together - Audacity allows you to do this, but it isn't the easiest thing in the world.

Comment: That's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend to some extent upon how the audio contained in the MP3 file was mixed. If:

- it was mixed in stereo, and
- the vocals were panned dead center in the stereo image, i.e. in mono, and
- the rest of the music in the recording has strong stereo components,

or

- there is some other feature unique to the audio of the vocals (e.g. their frequency range) that will let you filter them out without significantly affecting the rest of the recording

then you'll have a reasonable chance of lowering the level of the vocals, relative to the rest of the audio, to the point where mixing in a new vocal recording will effectively mask them.

[Here's](http://www.soundonsound.com/forum/showflat.php?Cat=0&Number=738835&page=784&view=collapsed&sb=10&o=&fpart=1) some good advice for someone else who asked a similar question.

Comment: or you have a multi track master ;)